# IOS 4.0 is it a way to add hipperlink kind of interaction to some range of NSMutableAttributetString?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-text

hi i'm building app with some rich text content on it and text content i have with NSMutableAttributedString. I cought links in my text with regex and made it blue but don't see the way to add some interaction to string ranges of NSAttributedString. is it any way? is there a way to do so?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

here is answer for my own question. I'm new to apple development so this project might be really dirty but it works for me, if anybody wants to improve it or has any suggestions please let me know, lets make this text project better ;) [textViewProject](http://creative.ge/xcode/textViewProject.zip)